# ASP.NET MVC User Control and Apostrophe being encoded

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, character-encoding, knockout.js, partial-views

Why would this user control have the apostrophes encoded?  It is causing issues with Jquery Templates.  The apostrophe is being encoded to `&#39;` from an AJAX request.

```
    <script type="text/html" id="editTimeTemplate">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(q => q.Time, new { type = "text", maxlength = 8, data_bind = "value: editTime.time.time, time: { options : { defaultTime: '8:00', showPeriod: true, showLeadingZero: false} }" })
    </script>
    <script type="text/html" id="editTimeTemplate">
    <input data-bind="value: editTime.time.time, time: { options : { defaultTime: &#39;8:00&#39;, showPeriod: true, showLeadingZero: false} }" id="Time" maxlength="8" name="Time" type="text" value="" />
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally the TextBoxFor uses a TagBuilder, which will do this encoding for all attribute values. The simple workaround is to not use a helper method, but an HTML tag (I am using MVC4, so the IdFor and NameFor methods you would have to implement yourself).

```
<input type="text" id="@Html.IdFor(m => m.Time)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.Time)" maxlength="8" data-bind="value: editTime.time.time, time: { options : { defaultTime: '8:00', showPeriod: true, showLeadingZero: false} }" />
```

or of course just:

```
<input type="text" id="Time" name="Time" maxlength="8" data-bind="value: editTime.time.time, time: { options : { defaultTime: '8:00', showPeriod: true, showLeadingZero: false} }" />
```

If this bothers you a lot (or you do this a lot) I would go the route of implementing my own TexBoxFor extension method and override any behavior you do not like.